# Can I plug a 2.5A 250V~ cable to a synth that is 100 - 240v?

Tags: synthesizer, electronics

I just got my new synthesizer, Waldorf Blofeld Keyboard.

I live in Korea and the power plug that came with won't match.

This is the plug that came with the keyboard:

[image]

and this is the receptacle on the back of the keyboard:

[image]

The Waldorf specs are

Nominal voltage: DC12V
Supply Voltage: 100-240v
Maximum current consumption: 0.3 A
Maximum power consumption: 5 W

I have playstation cable which is 2.5A 250V~

[image]

Could I plug this to my Waldorf Blofeld Keyboard ?

Would it be ok ?

Comment: This is just a pair of wires, which doesn’t do anything. 2.5A 250V~ only specifies how much electric power can flow through this cable. (That is, don’t plug it into a 380V socket. Or don’t use it for welding.)

Comment: Show us a pic of the lead that *did* come with it.

Comment: @Tim This is the cable that came with the Blofeld. https://imgur.com/6PcoEWQ

Comment: surely this is off-topic here?

Comment: Surely this is off-topic here...but do you need to hold a white cat in your arms while you play it?

Comment: Since you've linked the Sweetwater site, it looks like you probably bought it from the US? That's a North American-style plug. I've edited your image into the body to make that more obvious.

Comment: @DmitriUrbanowicz even that is unlikely to be disastrous... the cable would probably survive 380 V without problem, and I doubt you'll find any welding trafo with a C7 connector! The synth probably _won't_ like 380 V, but fortunately you also won't find a europlug-compatible 380 V outlet, so...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because altough this is about a musical instrument it is better answered on a site for electrical engineering or household appliances.

Answer (score 13):

The 2.5A and 250V on the cable is just the highest current (Ampere) and voltage (Volts) that it's safe to use at. Provided that your mains supply is in the range 100V to 240V then that's no problem.

If you're not sure about the voltage in your country take a look at the [Mains electricity by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country#Table_of_mains_voltages,_frequencies,_and_plugs) article on Wikipedia.

Comment: But the Playstation keyboard says 250v ~
does this mean I shouldn't use the cable ?

Comment: @HyunYooPark the cable is just a cable. It won't increase the voltage. If your wall socket has 240, 220 or even 120V, it will deliver the same to your keyboard's power supply.

Comment: @HyunYooPark - 250v ~ . The '~' means ac voltage. Dc is more like '='. There is a big difference  in electricity between the two. And they're not compatible.

Answer (score 7):

A simple cable with just wires and no electronics inside, as the one your photo shows, will simply forward any voltage. It won't change it.

The label on the cable specifies the maximum voltage it was made for. You can use it for any lower voltage as well. The `~` says that the voltage is alternating, in contrast to `=` where the voltage is constant (aka. direct).

I'm not sure how many different Waldorf Blofeld models exist, but one looks like this:

[image: Waldorf Blofeld AC connector]

If your keyboard has this connector labelled *AC In* (alternating current in), then your cable will fit into the wall on one side and into the keyboard on the other side.

No serious electronics engineer would construct a 12 V= plug with that kind of connector, simply because everybody expects to put 110 V~ or 230 V~ into it.

A typical low voltage DC connector looks like this:

[image: DC voltage connectors]

So there's no way you could accidentally mix a high voltage AC cable with a low voltage DC plug.

If your keyboard has a low voltage DC connector, then you need a power supply that converts 110 or 230 V~ to 12 V= like this (should have been shipped):

[image: Power supply]

As you can see, it has the high voltage connector on one side and the low voltage connector on the other side.

Answer (score 5):

<sup>This answer was provided before we had final details & pictures</sup>
To plug what to what??

If your cable fits the ***power supply*** for the keyboard, then that's fine.

If you're considering plugging it straight into the Waldorf directly, it will go ***BOOOM*** big time.

[I'm assuming it's the first - the second really shouldn't be physically possible. If it was, someone would have set their house on fire by now]

Comment: The shape of the jack looks fitting, but I was worried about the specs. https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/BlofeldKB--waldorf-blofeld-keyboard-white

Comment: @HyunYooPark - The terminal/jack on the keyboard is labeled "AC-IN".  You cable will both fit _and_ work based upon the specs you've quoted. :)

Answer (score 5):

Cite from the FAQ at https://support.waldorfmusic.com/products/Blofeld%20Keyboard

> Can I use my Blofeld Keyboard with the power grid in my country? 
>  The device comes with a wide range power supply which covers everything between 50-60 Hz and 110-240V. You just need a power cord with a "figure of 8" cable, also known as C7 connector and the other plug matching the power grid standard in your country. A voltage converter is not needed.

Cite from https://www.power-plugs-sockets.com/south-korea/

> In South Korea the power plugs and sockets are of type C and F. The
>   standard voltage is 220 V and the standard frequency is 60 Hz.

So your cable should fit.

Comment: Not sure whether 60Hz or 50Hz is good for the keyboard. Would that be relevant?

Comment: @Tim The FAQ says that the power supply works with everything between 50-60 Hz, so there should be no problem.

Answer (score 4):

No. The 250v is AC, and the keyboard is DC, and only 12volts. Completely incompatible.Playstation plug is a 'figure of eight' or 'Grundig' plug, used exclusively for mains powered items. It also gets used to power the black boxes (psu) which *do* transform 250vac into the 12vdc that your keyboard requires. But do not connect up direct. I can't think how you could anyway, as the keyboard will have a round socket for power, so it wouldn't (thankfully) fit.

EDIT _ I get it now! The figure of eight plug will fit your keyboard, it's just that the end which goes in the wall socket isn't right for your country! Any wire with the right plug ito the wall, and a figure of eight at the other end will do!

Comment: I think you mistaken the keyboard version with the desktop version.The blofeld keyboard version power socket have the shape of 8. https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/BlofeldKB--waldorf-blofeld-keyboard-white

Comment: It would be good to clarify whether the OP intends to plug the Playstation cable directly into the keyboard (via a DC-IN terminal), or use it to replace the stock wall cable for connecting from the wall outlet to the keyboard's powersupply brick/input. This answer is assuming the former case, although the latter scenario is more plausible and would work just fine given the stated "Supply Voltage: 100-240v".  As long as the wall outlet provides a volatage within that range it's fine to plug it into the AC-IN terminal (just **not** the DC-IN one).  As in 'wall -> power supply -> keyboard'.

Comment: FWIW the [images here](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/BlofeldKBBk--waldorf-blofeld-keyboard-black) suggest that the keyboard only has an AC-IN terminal, meaning the powersupply should be internal.  Thus it's fine (subject to the caveat that mains voltage must fall within the stated 100-240v range; which appears to hold for Korea, as Korea uses 220V).

Comment: @aroth I'm going to connect this straight to the Blofeld without going through any power supply brick.
The 8 shape plug is going in straight to Blofeld, and the other side is going straight to the multi plug socket.

Comment: If the keyboard has a socket that the figure of eight plug fits, then that will do the trick. It does say 'detachable ac in' on the specs, so assuming the wall ac is within the spec figures, it will be fine. NEVER plug that figure of eight into an XLR (canon) socket. It fits well, and cost me best part of £1000 to repair a keyboard I inadvertently did that with (in the dark on stage). NEVER again!

Comment: What do you mean by " so assuming the wall ac is within the spec figures " ?
This is the hole in my Blofeld Keyboard that I'm going to plug the cable. https://imgur.com/p12G0Gr

Comment: "Assuming the wall ac is within the spec figures" means simply that assuming the voltage coming out of the socket in the wall is around 240/250vac. There's nothing else it could mean! The spec figures on the keyboard you stated.

Comment: @Tim How do I know how much voltage is coming out of the wall ? Sorry if I'm keep misunderstanding, but to put it simple, is it a yes ? I could use the cable to my blofeld ?

Comment: You look at several items that *are* working from a wall socket. There will be a plate on them stating voltage - just like it does on the bottom of that plug. They'll probably say 220v, 230v, 240v. If so, they're the same as your keyboard. Think about it - plugs are different so it's (almost) impossible to put the wrong things together. Why haven't you asked the shop the keyboard came from?

Comment: @Tim I see,I did send a email, but waiting for the reply. Thanks for you answers !

Answer (score 3):

The Waldorf Blofeld requires a "tip positive" DC barrel connector supplying 12 Volt at least at 500 mA. The mains should only connect connect to a step down transformer and rectifier to convert it from 250 Volts AC to 12 Volts DC. Only use the mains PlayStation cable to the mains transformer.

Comment: OP says the socket on the keyboard is figure of eight. That's mains only, not DC. I thought it was a DC socket, but comment says no.

Answer (score -2):

User-available electric connections are generally engineered not to fit if they are not supposed to be connected.

Exceptions do exist, but your device has 100-240v range exactly not to be an exception.

So if it fits, plug (and play).